# Q: Python 3: Why bytearray element comparison b'ABC'[0] == b'A' equals False?

Tags: python, arrays

I am using bytearray to handle serial port data.

I know that the first byte of the data is a character, and I want to compare them.
This basically comes down to:

```
b'ABC'[0] == b'A'
```

This returns False, which I don't expect.

Comment: I answered my own question, but will gladly accept a more elegant answer that reassures my answer

Comment: `type(b'ABC'[0]), type(b'A')` => `(<class 'int'>, <class 'bytes'>)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The types don't match: `b'ABC'[0]` is a byte (actually an integer), `b'A'` is a bytearray of length 1 (actually 'bytes').
It can be solved by using:

```
b'ABC'[0] == b'A'[0]
```

Which returns True

Alternatively, also:

```
b'ABC'[0:1] == b'A'
```

Returns True, and in my case it is slightly more elegant: b'ABC' was stored in a variable, so it ends up being (I was looking for b'P'):

```
if data[0:1] == b'P':
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

`bytes` is an [immutable version of bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes).It has the same non-mutating methods and the same indexing and slicing behavior.Since `bytearray` objects are sequences of integers (akin to a list), **for a `bytearray` object b, `b[0]` will be an integer**, while `b[0:1]` will be a bytearray object of length 1.

So `b'ABC'[0] == b'A'` is comparing an `int` object to the `bytes` object resulting in `False`

```
>>> b'ABC'[0]
65
>>> type(b'A')
<class 'bytes'>
>>> b'ABC'[0] == b'A'
False
```

Comment: Thanks, I definitely took some of your points as inspiration to improve my own answer. But after those improvements, I think it is the most complete.

Comment: In 2 days I can ;)